# Making TextBox text theme aware

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I created a page.i want to change the background of Textbox when theme of emulator is changed to light.The letters cant be visible while changing the themes.is there any solution?

[image: light theme]

[image: dark theme]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can set a theme as default to our application.When we log in our application the phone theme will be changed to its suitable theme and when we log out change back to original
here s the [link](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/) .

Answer (score 1):

If you use the default TextBox control inside Visual Studio it is fully theme aware. If you have set the colours yourself then you need to perform the theme aware changes in code behind.

For more information, please see the following :-

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/ThemeawareWindowsPhoneapplication

Comment: The link is broken. There is no content available in that link

Comment: "There is currently no text in this page. You can search for this page title in other pages, or search the related logs." This is what it shows in my browser, don't know y :(

Comment: try this link: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Theme_aware_Windows_Phone_application , found by doing what it says and searching the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to `TextBlock` rather than `TextBox` (as the latter automatically has style support).

You should never declare a `TextBlock` without a `Style` attribute, such as `Style={StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}`. A full list of available styles can be found on MSDN: [Theme Resources for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_TextStyles)

Also of relevance is: [How to: Apply Theme Resources for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769545%28v=vs.92%29)

NB: Due to the way Mango was designed, *backing* into your application after changing themes will not apply the new theme. You will need to restart the application to see the changed theme.

**Update**

Based on your screenshots, you have two choices:

- Reskin ("Edit Template" in Blend) each of the controls that you use to redefine a style in which the various colour-related properties are hardcoded
- Use an alternate, lighter, background image when in the white theme in order to improve the contrast. I've [blogged about how you can define theme-aware resources](http://blog.richardszalay.com/2011/06/11/practical-support-for-light-dark-themes-on-windows-phone-7/) (and also mentioned it on other SO questions).

Put simply, you can either submit to the theme or force it to remain the way you want it.

Comment: No,i placed a textbox on an image background when i change the theme to light the textbox goes dark and also the fonts in it.can u help me?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot to your original question?

Comment: can u view the screenshots..i ve attached them